# Async calls from Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I am trying to make an asynchronous call from within my (Spring MVC based) Controller.

I am using the following snippet:

```
FutureTask<Object> runnableTask = new FutureTask<Object>(  
                new Runnable() {  
                    public void run() {  
                        // do something
                    }  

                }, null);  
runnableTask.run();
```

However, no matter what, this is not executed asynchronously, i.e., my Controller does not return back the response (to the view) until the above task completes. Am I missing something or is there an alternate way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an executor to do that:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newXx(..); //any executor, likely single-threaded
executor.submit(yourRunnable);
executor.shutdown();
```

But spring already has that ([docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async)) - just make a method and annotate it with `@Async` (and have `<task:annotation-driven />` in the xml)

Comment: The response is still held up, until the operations within the @Async method completes. Have added the annotaiton as well as `<task:annotation-driven/>`

Comment: the method should be public and invoked from another service.

Comment: the method is in a different service, but still...I tried dumping the thread ID, and looks like they are being executed in the same thread (rather than different). Not sure what is a miss here

Comment: perhaps <task:annotation driven is in the wrong xml? Where did you put it.

Comment: I put it in the correct XML - my app context XML. I think it does now work if you call an @Async method from within another method (i.e., it only works when called as a top-level method).

Comment: yes, that's correct. That's what I meant by "invoked from another service".

Comment: which means it won't work when called from a Controller, right?

Comment: if the method is in the service, and you call it form a controller - it will work

Comment: i thought so...but looks like it does not!

Comment: It does in my setup. But I can't see what is wrong with yours.

Comment: Even though this is pretty old, just for future reference sake:
The service actually needs to be a bean created by spring (I created it in the app context)
And then I autowired the bean to the controller I wanted to use it from, then it worked.

Comment: did you try to put it in [servlet-name]-servlet.xml?